# python 3 - ord expected a character

Tags: python

```
def toNumbers(strList):
    sum = 0
    strList[:]= (ord(ch)-96 for ch in strList)
    print(strList)


def main():
    print("Modifies each entry in the list by converting it to a number.")
    strList = [ "dd", "t", "c"]
    nums= toNumbers(strList)
main()
```

I get an error : ord expected a character. I think this is something to do with my for loop. Any assistance on this would be great.

Comment: Python code without indentation is not a [mcve].

Comment: cannot reproduce the error (maybe I shouldn't have fixed the indentation but I doubt it)

Comment: This works fine for me and prints [4, 20, 3]

Comment: Is this code supposed to demonstrate the problem? Or do you mean that you changed it to something else and caused an error? If so, post that

Comment: I can reproduce the error with `strList = [ "dd", "t", "c"]`

Comment: I have edited the post to show an error. Is this simple to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should read your error messages a little more carefully. What it actually said was

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

And your string of length 2 is `"dd"`.

Comment: Correct. However I want my code to accept the additional character length.

Comment: @karan "dd" is not a character. The [ord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) funtion only ever works with a string of length 1. Unless you split that string into two length 1 strings, that can never work.

Comment: ah okay thanks for that @RudiKershaw . Is there any way to get a string of characters in a list to be modified without using the ord function?

Comment: You don't say what you want to do with a 2-character stirng, but this will give yoiu something usable:  `strList = [[ord(ch) for ch in s] for s in strList]`.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks, but I want the characters in the list to to be represented as a value. e.g. abc (1,2,3) would equal 6.

Comment: @karan Then `[sum(ord(ch)-96 for ch in s) for s in strList]` should do it. But be aware it's a one-way conversion: information is lost. If `strList` is `['abc', 'cba', 'acb``']` the result will be `[6, 6, 6]`.